# Can anyone help identify this beautiful succulent?

Tags: identification, succulents

It's the tall one that looks like stacked flowers I'm asking about. Actual height is about 6 inches (15 cm).
[image: Tall succulent with stacked leaves]

Comment: It looks as if you've taken the photo with some sort of uv or violet lighting, so its difficult to tell the actual colours of the plant you want ID for - can you take another picture in daylight?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the violet  tint is not present on this plant, but is coming from a light above or nearby, it is Crassula perforata variegata, common name string of buttons - it does have coloured tints, but not violet ones https://worldofsucculents.com/crassula-perforata-variegata-variegated-string-of-buttons/

Comment: Thanks so much. It's under an LED full spectrum grow light, hence the violet tint.